# SQLiteDataAdapter.Fill() Stops all execution after. No exception raised

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, freeze, sqldataadapter

I have created a SQLite database file, by migrating the table schema, rows, etc from a SQL server instance on Azure. 
I created a util class to populate a DataSet object using a SQLiteDataAdapter object connected the the SQLite database, with a (Select * FROM Users) statement.
For some reason, I can execute a SQLite Reader just fine with the SQLiteCommand, and it returns the queried rows, which I print to the console. 
However whenever I try to execute an adapter.Fill(), it appears that nothing happens, and all code that should be executed afterwards(not dependent on anything done by the adapter itself), just ceases to do anything. There is NO exception raised, it simply stops...

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class SqliteInit

    Public Function getUserDataSet()

        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=users1.db;Version=3;"
        Dim mSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile;"
        Dim dataTable As New DataTable
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet
        dataSet.Tables.Add("UserProfile")

        Try

            If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
                MsgBox(" Computer is connected to the internet")

            Else
                MsgBox(" Computer is NOT connected")

                Dim SQLConn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
                Dim SQLComm As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand(mSQL, SQLConn)
                Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQLComm)

                SQLConn.Open()
                adapter.Fill(dataSet, "UserProfile")
                SQLConn.Close()

                Console.WriteLine("Empty")

                Return CType(dataSet, AzureDataSet)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Every other execution option seems to work with those defined objects, for example, I tested if I was accessing the database correctly by turning the statement into an insert, and sure enough when I executed the SqlCommand.NonQuery, it added the row. I also used a SQLiteReader with the Select statement, and it successfully printed the rows.
adapter.Fill seems to be the only thing breaking.

Comment: Are you sure there are no exceptions raised? You're catching all exceptions. Also, is there any particular reason why you aren't using `Using` statements?

Comment: I originally WAS using "using" statements, then changed them afterwards, thinking that may be whats causing the issue. Its the same result either way. Thanks for pointing out that its catching all exceptions, I got this code example from a tutorial and hadnt even realized that yet. I'll try to print the exception and stack trace and see what it gives me.

Comment: I've experienced the same.